# How to unify similar methods in c #

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I have various methods that does the same things.
Attached below the code :

```
    private async Task<CheckResponse> ManageCheckResponseError(string code)
    {
        await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
        return CheckResponse.GetError(code.ToString());
    }

    private async Task<BalanceResponse> ManageBalanceResponseError(string code)
    {
        await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
        return BalanceResponse.GetError(code.ToString());
    }

    private async Task<DebitResponse> ManageDebitResponseError(string code)
    {
        await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
        return DebitResponse.GetError(code.ToString());
    }

    private async Task<CreditResponse> ManageCreditResponseError(string code)
    {
        await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
        return CreditResponse.GetError(code.ToString());
    }

    private async Task<CancelResponse> ManageCancelResponseError(string code)
    {
        await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
        return CancelResponse.GetError(code.ToString());
    }
```

An example of these classes is as follows. All are made in the same way apart from the properties that obviously are different :

```
   public class SampleResponse : ICommonResponseOperations<SampleResponse>
   {
      // Props

      // Error Management
      public ErrorModel ErrorModel { get; set; }

      public static LoginResponse GetError(string code)
      {
        return new LoginResponse
        {
            Entry = "",
            EntryEmbedded = "",
            ErrorModel = ErrorModel.GetError(code)
        };
      }
  }
```

Is there a way through generics to standardize everything by making the code more elegant? Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code for those 4 classes? Is there any relationship between those 4 classes?

Comment: @YongShun done. Look post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next version of C# (11) you will be able to define static members of interfaces.

You can try that out in the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 by adding the following to your project file (assuming .NET 6.0):

```
<EnablePreviewFeatures>True</EnablePreviewFeatures>
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
```

After doing that you can modify your `ICommonResponseOperations` interface with a static member like so:

```
public interface ICommonResponseOperations<out TLoginResponse>
{
    static abstract TLoginResponse GetError(string code);
    // ... Other members
}
```

(You might need to remove the `out` depending on how the `TLoginResponse` type is used in the interface.)

Then you could define a common generic method like so:

```
private async Task<TLoginResponse> ManageResponseError<TLoginResponse>(string code) where TLoginResponse : ICommonResponseOperations<TLoginResponse>
{
    await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
    return TLoginResponse.GetError(code);
}
```

Then instead of:

```
private async Task<BalanceResponse> ManageBalanceResponseError(string code)
{
    await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
    return BalanceResponse.GetError(code.ToString());
}
```

You could just call `ManageResponseError<BalanceResponse>(code)` without having to specify a separate method to call.

Of course, C#11 isn't out yet and this feature is not *guaranteed* to make it, but it's looking pretty likely.

---

You can also simplify things a little with C#10.

You can write a generic method which accepts a `Func<string, TLoginResponse>` that it can call to return the necessary object:

```
public async Task<TLoginResponse> ManageResponseError<TLoginResponse>(
        string code, 
        Func<string /*code*/, TLoginResponse> getError)
    where TLoginResponse : ICommonResponseOperations<TLoginResponse>
{
    await LogErrorResponseAsync(new { StatusCode = code });
    return getError(code);
}
```

Then you can call the method without having to explicitly specify the generic type:

```
await ManageResponseError("some code", SampleResponse.GetError);
```

The generic type is inferred from the type of the lambda passed in at the call site.
Even the lambda itself (`code => SampleResponse.GetError(code)`) is inferred, so you only need to specify `SampleResponse.GetError`.

Comment: Before c#11 there is no way to semplify this???

Comment: @SimoneSpagna Added a section for C# 10

Comment: In my company they don't want to use sections. I, too, was used to using them to make the code more readable, but I was rejected in PR.

Comment: @SimoneSpagna Oh, I meant I added a new section to my answer, at the end: How to simplify the code using C# 10 and earlier.